# Starting hypothesys in the development of the eikonal equation

Tags: geometric-optics

In developing the iconal equation in the theory of geometric optics, I have studied that we start with this hypothesis *:

> The geometrical optics field is a solution to Maxwell's equations for
> which each field component has the same family of equiphase surfaces.
> This implies that, in a nonconducting isotropic medium that is not
> necessarily homogeneous, $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ can be
> expressed in the common form:
>
> $\mathbf{E}(x,y,z)=\mathbf{E}_0(x,y,z)e^{-jk\psi (x,y,z)}$
>
> $\mathbf{H}(x,y,z)=\mathbf{H}_0(x,y,z)e^{-jk\psi (x,y,z)}$
>
> where $k=\omega\sqrt{\mu_0\epsilon_0}$, $\psi$ is a pure real function
> and $\mathbf{E}_0(x,y,z)$, $\mathbf{H}_0(x,y,z)$ are generally
> complex.

My question is: what's the point of spelling out a phase factor in that way, if we then still allow that $\mathbf{E}_0(x,y,z)$ and $\mathbf{H}_0(x,y,z)$ can be complex functions?
In doing so, it seems to me, we do not get any particular case (compared to not doing it and leaving the generic functions $\mathbf{E}(x,y,z)$, $\mathbf{H}(x,y,z)$), because each component of $\mathbf{E}_0(x,y,z)$ and $\mathbf{H}_0(x,y,z)$ (having said that they can be complex) could all contain a common factor $e^{+jk\psi (x,y,z)}$, vanifying everything.
Maybe there is some more hypothesis that was not explicitly written?

- Robert S. Elliott, Antenna theory and design, IEEE Press Series on Electromagnetic Wave Theory, pag. 484.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This separation will be useful if $E_0$ and $H_0$ are slowly-varying functions of the coordinates, so that they can admit a Taylor series expansion. The eikonal approximation expands around the classical result, which corresponds to the wavelength of the light waves being small compared to other features in the problem. This corresponds large wave numbers $k$, so one can make approximations such as

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} E = e^{jk\Psi}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} E_0 + E_0 e^{jk\Psi} jk \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x} \approx E_0 e^{jk\Psi} jk \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial{x}}$.